# Pasting data from PowerPoint text boxes into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint that I need to copy the numbers in text boxes to a specific excel file.  I have decided to use a macro on the PowerPoint because the file will be shared with multiple users and I want to compile each file's data into a spreadsheet.  My code works fine so far, but only copies to a specific row and thus overwrites the existing data.  I am having trouble with the code for finding the next empty row.  What I tried so far only seems to work when going from excel to excel.

```
rw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

I am a novice at best when it comes to VBA.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
While xlsWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & row) <> ""
row = row + 1
Wend
```

This will find the next empty row and store the row number within the integer `row`. `xlsWB` is an `Object` which stores `CreateObject("Excel.Application").Workbooks.Open("File Path")`

Then, use the following syntax to fill in your cells.

```
xlsWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & row) = ""
```

Also, you can use a `For loop` to automate it.